# QFJ upgrade issue from 2.1.1 to 2.2.0 due to XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD

Tags: java-8, quickfixj

I am trying to upgrade the QFJ version 2.2.0 from 2.1.1 facing below issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
```

I have analysed this is because of QFJ DataDictionary.java's load method using below code.

```
 private void load(InputStream inputStream) throws ConfigError {
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
...}
```

Reason of error is not clearly understood by me(please try to explain) but found that Xerces, xercesImpl jar causing this error.

we are using these jar in some our project code that is why it is needed.

Can anyone try to explain why we have placed these lines? and we are placing then it should be under try and catch block. Is there any way to fix it. Without doing source code changes provide by QFJ.
Answer from QFJ team really appreciated.

Comment: If you suspect a bug in QuickFIX/J, the proper way to report it is on the [QuickFIX/J Issues](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues) page on GitHub.

Comment: thanks, I will also do that.

Comment: Started a discussion over https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/306

Comment: maybe fix with new commit: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/pull/307

Comment: Good to hear :-)